# Passing an HList to a function (with an implicit LeftFolder)

Tags: scala, fold, shapeless

I'm trying to write a small Rule/Validation engine that allows to chain rules via HLists. Now the code below compiles fine, but I'm not able to use the `Validation` class and as a beginner I got stuck here figuring out why.

```
trait Rule {
    type Value
}

object Rule {
    type Aux[T] = Rule { type Value = T }
}

abstract class RuleOps[R <: Rule]( rule: R )(
        implicit
        definition: Definition[R],
        show:       Show[R]
) {
   def validate( value: R#Value ): Result[R#Value] = {
        definition( value, rule ) match {
            case true  ⇒ Success( value )
            case false ⇒ Failure( value, Seq( show( value, rule ) ) )
        }
    }
}

case class Validation[T, H <: HList]( rules: H )(
    implicit fold: LeftFolder.Aux[H, T, combine.type, Result[T]]
) {
   def validate( value: T ): Result[T] = {
        rules.foldLeft( value )( combine )
    }
}

object Validation {
    object combine extends Poly {
        /**
         * First fold element retrieves a value input and generates either a
         * Success or a Failure
         */
        implicit def head[R <: Rule]( implicit definition: Definition[R], show: Show[R] ) = {
            use( ( value: R#Value, rule: R ) ⇒ rule.validate( value ) )
        }

        /**
         * If the previous fold returned a Success, the next rule is validated
         */
        implicit def success[R <: Rule]( implicit definition: Definition[R], show: Show[R] ) = {
            use( ( rule: R, success: Success[R#Value] ) ⇒ {
                head.apply( success.value, rule ) )
            }
        }

        /**
         * If the previous fold returned a Failure, all succeeding folds will
         * return Failures as well
         *
         * When this case fails, the additional error messages are appended to
         * the input Failure. In case of a successful validation, the input
         * Failure is passed along.
         */
        implicit def failure[R <: Rule]( implicit definition: Definition[R], show: Show[R] ) = {
            use( ( rule: R, failure: Failure[R#Value] ) ⇒ {
                rule.validate( failure.value ) match {
                    case Failure( _, messages ) ⇒
                        ( lens[Failure[R#Value]] >> 'messages ).modify( failure )( _ ++ messages )
                    case Success( _ ) ⇒ failure
                }
            } )
        }
    }
}
```

Using `Validation` yields an implicit missing error

```
> Validation( Required[String]() :: Email() :: HNil ).validate( "asdf" )
> [error] could not find implicit value for parameter fold: LeftFolder.Aux[Required[String] :: Email :: HNil, T, combine.type, Result[T]]
> [error]     Validation( Required[String]() :: Email() :: HNil ).validate( "asdf" )
> [error]               ^
> [error] one error found
```

I suspected the fold cases additional implicits parameters (`defintion` & `show`) to be the cause of this, but temporarily removing them did not have an impact on the error.

**Update** [Working code example](http://pastebin.com/pL0wPiLB)

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? It's likely that the type projections are the problem, but it's difficult to debug this without knowing what your `use` does, or without being able to try to compile something.

Comment: use is a shapeless poly helper, but I'm trying to break the code down into a working example.

Comment: I added a working example to the post and got a better understanding of what is going wrong while putting that together. I think I might be able to solve it now with some additional research. But I'd still love to see your solution: Your SO posts are the best resource to educate about shapeless and the weird ways of Scala type level programming. I feel like every documented code snippet is bringing me a tiny little bit forward ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to put a working solution together. And I think my mistake was to match against `Failure` and `Success`, rather than `Result`. But that is more like a gut feeling..

The runtime pattern matching in `caseTail` is somewhat cumbersome, but I'm fine with that as a proof of concept.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder

trait Rule {
    type Value
}
object Rule {
    type Aux[T] = Rule { type Value = T }
}

implicit class RuleOps[R <: Rule]( rule: R )(
        implicit
        definition: Definition[R],
        show:       Show[R]
) {
    def validate( value: R#Value ): Result[R#Value] = {
        definition( value, rule ) match {
            case true  ⇒ Success( value )
            case false ⇒ Failure( value, Seq( show( value, rule ) ) )
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Type class that defines the actual validation logic
 */
trait Definition[-R <: Rule] {
    def apply( value: R#Value, rule: R ): Boolean
}

/**
 * Type class that renders an error message for a failed rule validation
 */
trait Show[-R <: Rule] {
    def apply( value: R#Value, rule: R ): String
}

/**
 * A Result is the outcome of a rule(s) validation
 */
sealed trait Result[+T] { def value: T }
case class Success[+T]( value: T ) extends Result[T]
case class Failure[+T]( value: T, messages: Seq[String] ) extends Result[T]

/**
 * Validate a value against a list of rules
 */
case class Validation[T, H <: HList]( rules: H )( implicit f: LeftFolder.Aux[H, T, combine.type, Result[T]] ) {
    def validate( value: T ): Result[T] = rules.foldLeft( value )( combine )
}

object combine extends Poly2 {
    implicit def caseHead[R <: Rule](
        implicit
        definition: Definition[R],
        show:       Show[R]
    ): Case.Aux[R#Value, R, Result[R#Value]] = {
        at[R#Value, R]( ( value, rule ) ⇒ {
            rule.validate( value )
        } )
    }

    implicit def caseTail[T, R <: Rule.Aux[T]](
        implicit
        definition: Definition[R],
        show:       Show[R]
    ): Case.Aux[Result[T], R, Result[T]] = {
        at[Result[T], R]( ( result, rule ) ⇒ {
            rule.validate( result.value )
        } )
    }
}

trait Email extends Rule {
    override type Value = String
}

object Email extends Email {
    implicit val dfn = new Definition[Email] {
        override def apply( value: String, rule: Email ) = false
    }

    implicit val show = new Show[Email] {
        override def apply( value: String, rule: Email ) = "error.email"
    }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.LeftFolder
defined trait Rule
defined object Rule
defined class RuleOps
defined trait Definition
defined trait Show
defined trait Result
defined class Success
defined class Failure
defined class Validation
defined object combine
defined trait Email
defined object Email

scala> Email.validate( "asdf" )
res0: Result[Email.Value] = Failure(asdf,List(error.email))

scala> Validation( Email :: HNil ).validate( "asdf" )
res1: Result[String] = Failure(asdf,List(error.email))

scala> Validation( Email :: Email :: HNil ).validate( "asdf" )
res2: Result[String] = Failure(asdf,List(error.email))
```